# YAML: multiple fields in one line

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

How can I write multiple fields in one line Loader=yaml.FullLoader?

Eg. turn this:

```yaml
field:
   item0: 0
   item1: 1
```

into this:

```yaml
field:
  item0:0, item1:1
```

Or even:

```yaml
field: {item0:0, item1:1}
```

Eg. in JSON you could do:

```json
{"field":{ "item0":0, "item1":1 }}
```

How can you do the same thing in YAML?

Answer (score 1):

YAML is designed to be a superset of JSON, so your JSON one-liner would also work with a YAML parser:

```
import yaml

print(yaml.load('{"field":{ "item0":0, "item1":1 }}', Loader=yaml.FullLoader))
```

and since the field names are all alphabets in your example, you can omit the quotes:

```
print(yaml.load('{field: {item0: 0,item1: 1}}', Loader=yaml.FullLoader))
```

both would produce the output:

```
{'field': {'item0': 0, 'item1': 1}}
```